# Can a block of CSS code be made non-functioning with !important?

Tags: css, joomla2.5

I am working in Joomla and the CSS that comes with a third-party has the following CSS code that is causing a conflict and I was told to have it removed:

```
[class*="span"] {
     float: left;
     margin-left: 20px;
     min-height: 1px;
}
```

I don't want to remove this from the "core" of the third-party component because when an update comes in, it will overwrite this. I normally put in CSS I want to override in the template's custom.css file with !important and that has worked.

Is there a way, perhaps using !important to do the equivalent of removing the above block of CSS code so it doesn't function? I'm not a CSS expert, but is there a way of putting this in the custom.css that would make this CSS block non-functioning so it doesn't interfere? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes

```
[class*="span"] {
     float: none !important;
     margin-left: none !important;
     min-height: none !important;
}
```

But, unless there's a JS plugin loading that CSS on page load, there's no need. Include your CSS **after** the third-party's version, which you should always do anyway.

```
[class*="span"] {
     float: none;
     margin-left: none;
     min-height: none;
}
```

Example HTML

```
<link href="/css/joomla.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/css/third-party.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

custom.css rules will override third-party.css rules.

Answer (score 0):

One way I would do it to give CSS class to my body. Say "myCustomClass" then.. override the above class as follows:

```
.mycustomclass [class*="span] {
        add properties
 }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ankitvijay/n4Enb/

Comment: Wouldn't that require modifying the core of the third-party vendor's CSS to define .mycustomclass to make that work?

Comment: You don't need to. You can have your own custom style sheet for that. The advantage is you can use the class whichever page you like.

Comment: As I mentioned, I'm not a CSS expert. So .mycustomclass is overwriting the function of what "[class*="span]..." does?

Comment: Yes, Exactly. If you need it to a specific span then other way to achieve this is: http://jsfiddle.net/ankitvijay/7P6Ek/1/